# How to increase the delay that is taken to start an application when an icon is clicked in the ubuntu launcher?

Tags: ubuntu

My problem is that It regularly happens that I click on the wrong icon into the ubuntu launcher and then an application is started that I don't want.
Is there a way to increase the time that I have to click on an icon to start an application using the unity launcher ?
Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here, is don't click on the wrong icon.